# Iterating through date ranges

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

Given this code:

```
def doc_chart_data(document)
  (1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date| {
      date: date,
      hits: Impression.where(:impressionable_id => document).where(:created_at => date).count
      }
  end
end
```

How would I change the `date` in the SQL query to be that **whole** day and not just a specific timestamp? There's all the date range answers with `Time.now` and all, but I don't really know how to write one in a situation where the dates are automatically mapped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Impression.where(:impressionable_id => document).where("YEAR(created_at) = ? && MONTH(created_at) = ? && DAY(created_at) = ?",date.year,date.month,date.day).count
```